# How to create a table without uninstalling and reinstalling the module?

Tags: installation

I have a module and an installation file that is used to create a table.

According to my requirement, I need to add an another table in the same install file. I know that by using `hook_schema()` we can create n number of tables.
But we need to uninstall and reinstall again to create the tables. If I use this, my existing data will be lost, so I am not supposed to do this.

Is there any way to create a table without uninstalling and reinstalling the module?

Comment: Can you specify which version of Drupal we're using ?

Comment: I am using Drupal 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link answered my question: [Updating tables: hook_update_N() functions](http://drupal.org/node/150215).

For example:

In Drupal 7:

```
<?php
/**
 * Create new database table {mytable2}.
 */
function mymodule_update_7101() {
  $schema['mytable2'] = array(
     // table definition array goes here
  );
  db_create_table('mytable2', $schema['mytable2']);
}
?>
```

and in Drupal 6:

```
<?php
/**
 * Create new database table {mytable2}.
 */
function mymodule_update_6101() {
  $schema['mytable2'] = array(
     // table definition array goes here
  );
  $ret = array();
  db_create_table($ret, 'mytable2', $schema['mytable2']);
  return $ret;
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to also add the new table schema in your hook_shema, otherwise for the new install you'll not have the added table.

Answer (score 0):

[hook_install()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) is called only when the module is first installed; after that, `hook_install()` will be called only if you first uninstall the module.

When you are updating a module, you need to implement [hook_update_N()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7), which runs all times the module is updated. At the same time, the implementation of [hook_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) needs to be updated to include all the schema used from the module, for who installs the module for the first time.